# how to drag a google.maps.polyline and retrieve the Lat Lng coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to retrieve the coordinates from polyline after drag. But i have no success.

Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
var virtualReferencePointPolyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({                  
path: wayCoordinates,                      
strokeColor: mRouteColor,
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
editable: true,
draggable: true,
strokeWeight: 1                 

 });

virtualReferencePointPolyLine.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine, 'dragend',       function(evt){
        alert("xx");
        evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dragend event doesn't work on an editable polyline.  If I just make it draggable (remove the `editable:true`), that event works:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8fxaq6p3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var wayCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.45, -122.15),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.44, -122.14)
  ];
  var mRouteColor = "#FF0000";
  var virtualReferencePointPolyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: wayCoordinates,
    strokeColor: mRouteColor,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    // editable: true,
    draggable: true,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  virtualReferencePointPolyLine.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine, 'dragend', function(evt) {
    // alert("xx");
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "polyline points:" + "<br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
    }
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

If you want the line to be editable, you need to add the event listeners to the `path` of that polyline, which is an [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCArray), so add:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'insert_at', polylineChanged);
google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'remove_at', polylineChanged);
google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'set_at', polylineChanged);

function polylineChanged() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "polyline points:" + "<br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getLength(); i++) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += this.getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8fxaq6p3/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var wayCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.45, -122.15),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.44, -122.14)
  ];
  var mRouteColor = "#FF0000";
  var virtualReferencePointPolyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: wayCoordinates,
    strokeColor: mRouteColor,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    editable: true,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  virtualReferencePointPolyLine.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'insert_at', polylineChanged);
  google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'remove_at', polylineChanged);
  google.maps.event.addListener(virtualReferencePointPolyLine.getPath(), 'set_at', polylineChanged);

}

function polylineChanged(evt) {

  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "polyline points:" + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getLength(); i++) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += this.getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```